# Why is Typescript unable to infer the correct type based off an enum switch statement?

Tags: typescript

```
enum Test {
  one,
  two,
}

const play = (n: Test) => {
  switch (n) {
    case Test.one:
      return 'hello';
    case Test.two:
      return {};

    default:
      exhaustive(n);
      throw new Error('hi');
  }
};

const b = play(Test.one);

//
console.log(b);
```

Can someone help me understand why Typescript can't infer that the return type of `play(Test.one)` is a string instead of an object?  Also, if there's something I can do to make it work, I would love to know that as well.

Typescript 3.9.4

Hovering over the typeof b yields:
[image: wrong inferred type]

Comment: well thanks for that downvote, stackoverflow never dissappoints :). I actually looked around for quite some time for a specific example like this and was unable to find anything as concrete as this, or the examples were a lot more complex.  If someone has a link to something helpful that would still be much appreciated :)

Comment: It's not a bad question. not sure why it was downvoted :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typescript will not try to infer anything like this accurately (basically infer overloads based on the switch statements). The best you can hope for from TS inference is a union of all possible return types. In your case you get the return type as `{}` because most types are compatible with `{}`, even `string` so the union `{} | string` simplifies to `{}`.

Your only solution here is to be explicit about the return types using multiple overloads (although you will need a function declaration, overloads can't be defined on a function expression):

```
function play(n: Test.one): "hello"
function play(n: Test.two): {}
function play(n: Test) {
    switch (n) {
        case Test.one:
            return 'hello';
        case Test.two:
            return {};

        default:
            exhaustive(n);
            throw new Error('hi');
    }
};

const b = play(Test.one); // "hello"
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=25&ssc=1&pln=9&pc=1#code/KYOwrgtgBAKsDOAXKBvAUFTUD2JgBoMtEB3bQgXzQDMwQBjRAS1ymAA8ALAQzCSYBuwABQgAXFDxCATgEpUaNFRp1GLEFAAOAG24BPURLhIAdLmCyJAIk7Bt27FZUNmrHfsOwEiE6WyXUKloXdS1dA3EvJHl0LCh4EiZEek4oURiiOMx6bnhgKJ9zMUysuOlgRDBpDQByW3tsGoBuEricvILfMmLS0vLK6sCW1qwAE2BqXm1EHt64jh4+ZiF0lrm4xE5pbBJJYF2AUWlt6WE6phrZNawqCmH6XCQoACMoAF4wj2NCvCuoAHp-lAbHYHE40IC0A8QPBsNpgCYHABzYTPK5AA)

Note: Your implementation will not be checked against the overloads, so it's up to you to ensure that implementation and overloads agree.

Comment: Super helpful information with the overloading technique.  Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

The reason is that every return value has a different type one returns a string one returns an object and one an error. This way linter will choose the base class which is object